# How to return data and url as ajax result in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi how to send the url of viewdetails and the result calculated data to the ajax call.

```
public ActionResult viewdetails(FormCollection form)
{
    String uname = Convert.ToString(form["uname"]);
    String mail = Convert.ToString(form["umail"]);
     return Json(new { sum = uname + mail, url = Url.Action("MyAction", "viewdetails") });
    //need to return the result value and url of viewdetails page      
}

success: function (result) {     
           window.location = result.url;      
    }
```

but the above code lead to error `This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return Json(new { sum = uname + mail, url = Url.Action("MyAction", "viewdetails") }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```